# How to dynamically change the grouping of HTML elements using a dropdown and HTML5 data attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this dropdown:

```
<select>
  <option value="group1">Name</option>
  <option value="group2" data-group-order="[Odds|Evens]">Odds First then Even</option>
  <option value="group3" data-group-order="[Most Favorites|Somewhat Favorites|Least Favorites]">Most to least favorite</option>
</select>
```

and this HTML:

```
<div id="Item1" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="5" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 1</div>
<div id="Item2" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 2</div>
<div id="Item3" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="4" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 3</div>
<div id="Item4" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 4</div>
<div id="Item5" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="3" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 5</div>
<div id="Item6" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 6</div>
<div id="Item7" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="2" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="2">Item 7</div>
<div id="Item8" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="3">Item 8</div>
<div id="Item9" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 9</div>
<div id="Item10" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 10</div>
```

When selecting an option from the dropdown, I can I dynamically update the HTML so that what the user sees is a grouping of the divs based on the option elements "data-group-order" value, with each div inside of that group being ordered by the value of their "data-groupX-order" attribute?

For example, if I selected the "Name" option (value=group1) I would expect:

```
<div>Name</div>
<div id="Item1" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="5" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 1</div>
<div id="Item2" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 2</div>
<div id="Item3" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="4" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 3</div>
<div id="Item4" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 4</div>
<div id="Item5" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="3" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 5</div>
<div id="Item6" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 6</div>
<div id="Item7" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="2" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="2">Item 7</div>
<div id="Item8" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="3">Item 8</div>
<div id="Item9" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 9</div>
<div id="Item10" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 10</div>
```

If I selected "Odds First then Even" option (value=group1, data-group-order="[Odds|Evens]") I would expect:

```
<div>Odds</div>
<div id="Item9" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 9</div>
<div id="Item7" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="2" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="2">Item 7</div>
<div id="Item5" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="3" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 5</div>
<div id="Item3" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="4" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 3</div>
<div id="Item1" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="5" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 1</div>
<div>Evens</div>
<div id="Item2" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 2</div>
<div id="Item4" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 4</div>
<div id="Item6" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 6</div>
<div id="Item8" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="3">Item 8</div>
<div id="Item10" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 10</div>
```

If I selected "Most to least favorite" option (value=group3 data-group-order="[Most Favorites|Somewhat Favorites|Least Favorites]" I would expect:

```
<div>Most Favorites</div>
<div id="Item9" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 9</div>
<div id="Item4" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 4</div>
<div id="Item6" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 6</div>
<div>Somewhat Favorites</div>
<div id="Item7" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="2" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="2">Item 7</div>
<div id="Item10" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 10</div>
<div>Least Favorites</div>
<div id="Item2" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 2</div>
<div id="Item3" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="4" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 3</div>
<div id="Item8" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="3">Item 8</div>
<div id="Item5" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="3" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 5</div>
<div id="Item1" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="5" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 1</div>
```

*Note* that when ordering within a grouping using "data-groupX-order" the order is based on that value and then alphanumerically in the case the multiple elements share the same value.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach. Note that I avoided to use order all together. I base the sort on `data-group2-name` but have a `dict` variable that tracks the order in which I want these different name values to appear. The reason for that is that having to maintain the order value manually makes it far too likely to forget to update one item.

Alphabetical numbering for elements with the same value is done by sorting on name first, then applying the group order (note that in alphabetical order, 'Item 10' comes before 'Item 2').

```js
function handleSelectChange(event) {
 var selectEl = event.target;
 var gp = selectEl.value;
 var dict = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].dataset.groupOrder;
 dict = (dict || '').replace(/\[(.*?)\]/, "$1").split('|');
 groupChildren(
     document.getElementById('orderedThroughSelect'),
     gp, 
     dict
 );
}

function groupChildren(el, gp, dict) {
 // --- getting the list of nodes to sort
 var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children);
 // --- ordering
 // start by ordering options in alphabetical order
 var nodeText = function(node) { return node.innerText; };
 var alphabeticAsc = function(a, b) { return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0; };
 nodes.sort(function(a, b) { return alphabeticAsc(nodeText(a), nodeText(b)); });
 // now order by group
 if(dict) { 
     var nodeGroupIndex = function(node) { return  dict.indexOf(node.dataset[gp+'Name']);  };
     var numericAsc = function(a, b) { return a - b; };
     nodes.sort(function(a, b) { return numericAsc(nodeGroupIndex(a), nodeGroupIndex(b)); });
 }
 // --- reseting content
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 nodes.forEach(function(el) { div.appendChild(el); });
 el.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<select onchange='handleSelectChange(event)'>
  <option value="group1">Name</option>
  <option value="group2" data-group-order="[Odds|Evens]">Odds First then Even</option>
  <option value="group3" data-group-order="[Most Favorites|Somewhat Favorites|Least Favorites]">Most to least favorite</option>
</select>


<div id='orderedThroughSelect'>
 <div id="Item1" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="1" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="5" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 1</div>
 <div id="Item2" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="2" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 2</div>
 <div id="Item3" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="3" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="4" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 3</div>
 <div id="Item4" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="4" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 4</div>
 <div id="Item5" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="5" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="3" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 5</div>
 <div id="Item6" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="6" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="10">Item 6</div>
 <div id="Item7" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="7" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="2" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="2">Item 7</div>
 <div id="Item8" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="8" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Least Favorites" data-group3-order="3">Item 8</div>
 <div id="Item9" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="9" data-group2-name="Odds" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Most Favorites" data-group3-order="1">Item 9</div>
 <div id="Item10" data-group1-name="Name" data-group1-order="10" data-group2-name="Evens" data-group2-order="1" data-group3-name="Somewhat Favorites" data-group3-order="5">Item 10</div>
</div>
```